# Float div on top of div that has scroll-y

Tags: jquery, html, css, fixed

So I want a div to scroll when user scrolls div (notice div) down. Here's the html:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="floaty">Yep</div>
content
</div>
```

So the container is about 700px height (dynamic height depending on content inside) but it has set in css scroll y and x. So when srolling content you don't scroll the whole page. But now the floaty thing keeps still top of div even though it has position fixed. I believe it's because browser looks that page is not scrolling so it doesn't move it.

Container has also position relative set. So how can i make it scroll? Is jQuery only way?

Comment: can you please provide a live example of your code? ty

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try:

```
.container{
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin-top:50px;
    width:100%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
.floaty{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid green;
    top:0px;
}
```

I am not sure is this the final result you expect, but if not -please,clarify.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aLUpr/)

Comment: This is what I have at the moment and for some reason the floaty div doesn't move when scrolled. But seems it's something in my markup or css then. It should work like your example shows. darn it... what could cause it not to work.. hmm

Comment: where do you want to move the  'floaty' div?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the floaty div to scroll with the content (and it's not clear if this is the case), you need to make it position absolute to the container.

```
.container{
position:relative;
height:200px;
border:1px solid #000000;
margin-top:50px;
width:300px;
overflow-y:scroll;
}
.floaty{
position:absolute;
top:0; //or wherever you want it to float
left:0;
background:#eaeaea;
width:300px;
height:50px;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aLUpr/2/)